# Implementing an onclick event without JQuery

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a bit of JQuery in my app that adds a click event to a class. The click event just removes a class on the parent element.

```
$(function(){
  $(".flash .close").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
  })
});
```

This is the only use of JQuery in my entire application, so I'd love to re-write this snippet without JQuery so I can eliminate that as a dependency all together.

However, I'm not sure where to begin in terms of implementing this click even in native javascript. I don't know much about JavaScript and the little that I do know involves frameworks like JQuery and React.

Thanks!

Comment: removing jquery tag

Comment: querySelectorAll, addEventListener, classList. Learn how to use it, seems like a pretty basic task.

Comment: add , in between elements class name.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello - would you mind detailing that a bit further? I'm not sure how any of those are implemented.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `querySelectorAll` for select the element.Then `classList.remove()` use for remove the class name of the [`parentElement`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) .

```js
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelectorAll(".flash ,  .close").forEach(function(a){
a.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  })
  })
}
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
<a class="flash">hi</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from the source below for your learning perspective
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/z6uopyhy/1/

```
var flashCloseButton = document.getElementsByClassName('close');

for(var i = 0; i < flashCloseButton.length; i++){
     flashCloseButton[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    this.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
     });
}
```